# Installing and Using React from React repo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very basic question: I'm required to install and use react through the artifact files [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases). I downloaded the two files as seen in my directory. I'm using babel as my transpiler. I'm aware there are better ways to go about install react via npm, script file locations, etc but I have to do it this way. Here's a picture of my directory - [image]

I feel like I have the relevant scripts and imports everywhere but I'm getting these errors -

```
app.js:1 GET http://localhost:3000/public/react.development.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
app.js:2 GET http://localhost:3000/public/react-dom.development.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I seem to have an error from actually reading the two .js files I downloaded from the repo itself as well as the location of those files when calling them in my app.jsx. I've included the script files to run in my index.html file

```
  <script src='react-dom.development.js'></script>
  <script src='react.development.js'></script>
```

In my app.jsx I have these import statements

```
import React from '../public/react.development.js';
import ReactDOM from '../public/react-dom.development.js';
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here. I'm not sure why I'm getting a 404 finding the files even though the given path is correct but it's still wrong somehow?

Comment: “Unexpected token <“ smells of a 404 http error, but usually that happens in a JSON parse.

Comment: Well, I should've mentioned but the odd thing is from the react/reactdom files i downloaded from the repo both start with `<!DOCTYPE html>` which is what the error is pointing to. I'm not sure if I downloaded the incorrect files or I'm not using them properly

Comment: How did you download them? JS file should not contain doctypes...

Comment: Yeah. I just realized that when I replied to you and took a look at the actual file.. I downloaded it as "Save link as" option". This is the file I want to download https://unpkg.com/browse/react@16.13.1/cjs/react.development.js but I don't actually see a link or option to download the file which is why I did what I did

Comment: Click “view raw”

Comment: Doh.. I see. I'll save it and see if that fixes my issue. Thanks for the basic troubleshooting  lol

Comment: No problem. I’m glad you got it sorted. If something still doesn’t work, consider making a new question rather than continuing this one.

Comment: Thanks. Still getting a 404 error of not found for my react files. I would make a new question, but I'm going to have to wait for some time. I'll hope that someone else can drop in and answer

Comment: How do you run your localhost?